# How to unregister a class in mono touch

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono

In monotouch using c# I have used `[Register("CpyRightCusTabVwCell")]` above the afore mentioned class. Now I want to un-register that class. How do I do that in monotouch using C#?

```cs
using System;
using MonoTouch;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Net.Mime;
using NUnitLite.Runner;

namespace egUniSBPersHlthCareManager
{

    [Register("CpyRightCusTabVwCell")]
    public partial class CpyRightCusTabVwCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public CpyRightCusTabVwCell(IntPtr handel):base (handel)
        {

        }
        public CpyRightCusTabVwCell ()
        {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Class registration is for life (of the process).